# Increment variable by more than 1?

Tags: javascript, increment

Here's my script :

```
function itemQuantityHandler(operation, cart_item) {
  var v = cart_item.quantity;

  //add one
  if (operation === 'add' && v < settings.productBuyLimit) {
    v++;
  }

  //substract one
  if (operation === 'subtract' && v > 1) {
    v--;
  }

  //update quantity in shopping cart
  $('.item-quantity').text(v);

  //save new quantity to cart
  cart_item.quantity = v;
}
```

What I need is to increase `v` (`cart_item.quantity`) by more than one. Here, it's using `v++`, but it's only increasing by 1. How can I change this to make it increase by 4 every time I click on the plus icon?

I tried

```
v++ +4
```

But it's not working.

Comment: `v += 4`...? And some padding...

Comment: If you don't know how to add 4 to a number, I'd really suggest running through a basic programming tutorial.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use a compound assignment operator:

```
v += 4;
```

Comment: Not equivalent: `v += 4` only evaluates the expression once, which is good when it's a long expression or it has side effects.

Comment: v+=1 acts like ++v not v++

Answer (score 22):

Use `variable += value;` to increment by more than one:

```
v += 4;
```

It works with some other operators too:

```
v -= 4;
v *= 4;
v /= 4;
v %= 4;
v <<= 1;
v >>= 4;
```

Comment: For reference: See [Addition Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment) (`+=`) and [Subtraction Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Subtraction_assignment) (`-=`) operators.

Comment: ||= and &&= don't seem to exist in JavaScript. |= and &= perform bitwise assignment operators which are just as good if you're not doing direct === comparisons to actual booleans.

Comment: You're right @Csit - I must have been thinking in a different language when I wrote this.

Answer (score 3):

To increase v by n:
    v += n

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//event handler for item quantity in shopping cart
    function itemQuantityHandler(p, a) {
        //get current quantity from cart
        var filter = /(\w+)::(\w+)/.exec(p.id);
        var cart_item = cart[filter[1]][filter[2]];
        var v = cart_item.quantity;


        //add four
        if (a.indexOf('add') != -1) {
            if(v < settings.productBuyLimit) v += 4;
        }
        //substract one
        if (a.indexOf('subtract') != -1) {
            if (v > 1) v--;

        }
        //update quantity in shopping cart
        $(p).find('.item-quantity').text(v);
        //save new quantity to cart
        cart_item.quantity = v;
        //update price for item
      $(p).find('.item-price').text((cart_item.price*v).toFixed(settings.numberPrecision));
        //update total counters 
        countCartTotal();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

`var i = 0;
    function buttonClick() {
        x = ++i*10 +10;
    }`